# Up/Down navigation between 100vh divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a website divided into divs that share common class but have different IDs. Each div takes 100vh. Scrolling is disabled and to let user move from page to page I'd like to create navigation with Up/Down clickable arrow images.

I wrote this JS script for those buttons. When I analyze it line after line it seems it should work, but it doesn't :( I'll appreciate any help

```
<div id="1" class="slideContainer"> </div>
<div id="2" class="slideContainer"> </div>
<div id="3" class="slideContainer"> </div>

<div class="up" id="up">
    <img src="img/up.png">
</div>
<div class="down" id="down">
     <img src="img/down.png">
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click", goUp); 

function goUp() {
    var visibleId =  $("div.slideContainer:visible").prev().attr('id');
    var targetID = visibleId
    document.getElementById(targetID).scrollIntoView();

}

document.getElementById("down").addEventListener("click", goDown); 

function goDown() {
    var visibleId =  $("div.slideContainer:visible").next().attr('id');
    var targetID = visibleId
    document.getElementById(targetID).scrollIntoView();

}
```

Comment: my bad, I meant up-down images of arrows that can be clicked with mouse

Comment: Unless you are doing something that you aren't showing, Elements are considered `visible` if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero. So even if the div isn't in the viewport, it is still technically visible. You could maybe try checking if the top left corner of the div is 0,0.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just throw an `active` class on the one that is displayed, and move it around as you swap in/out the pseudo-views.

Comment: have you considered working with anchors in addition to a smooth scroll script? You still can disable scoll ability for the user but can jump to the divs calling their ID as an anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any library, i think you can use this.

```js
$('#up').on('click', function() {
    var mId = $(this).parent().siblings('.active');
    if (mId.attr('id') === '1') {
        return false;
    } else {
        mId.prev('.slideContainer').addClass('active');
        mId.removeClass('active');
    }
});
$('#down').on('click', function() {
    var mId = $(this).parent().siblings('.active');
    if (mId.attr('id') === '3') {
        return false;
    } else {
        mId.next('.slideContainer').addClass('active');
        mId.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
.img-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.img-wrapper > div:not(:first-child) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
}
.img-wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
    z-index: 2;
    top: 100%;
}
.img-wrapper div:nth-child(4) {
    z-index: 3;
    top: 100%;
}
.img-wrapper div.active {
    top: 0;
}
.control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
}
.control div {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background-color: green;
    color: yellow;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img-wrapper">
    <div id="contr0l" class="control">
        <div class="up" id="up">
            Up
        </div>
        <div class="down" id="down">
             Down
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="1" class="slideContainer active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1280/720" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="slideContainer">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1280/720" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="slideContainer">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1020/1280/720" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to use library, i suggest the [fullpage](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) one, very cool, can use with animate.css too